# Uniqiue background on every page

Tags: php, jquery, css, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7. My bg image in page.tpl.php file and image get to css.

My html:

```
<div class="mainimage" id="mainimg" class="clearfix"></div>
```

And CSS:

```
#mainimg {
    background: url("../img/mainimg.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 500px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -640px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1280px;
    z-index: 1;
    top:0;
}
```

My bg image seen all pages. It's normally. But i want, change my bg image on every page. 
E.G.

```
...
mysite.com/index.php -bg image: mainimg.jpg
mysite.com/news -bg image:news.jpg
mysite.com/about -bg image: about.jpg
...
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [built-in Drupal functions](http://drupal.org/node/32077) to add a unique identifier to the `body`, so you can target each page individually in your CSS.

For example, if the body had `id="news"`, you could change the background image by adding this to your CSS:

```
#news #mainimg {
    background-image: url("../img/news.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a different class per each page.

### mysite.com/news

HTML

```
<div class="mainimage news-bg" id="mainimg" class="clearfix"></div>
```

CSS

```
.news-bg {
    background: url("../img/news-bg.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

### mysite.com/about

HTML

```
<div class="mainimage about-bg" id="mainimg" class="clearfix"></div>
```

CSS

```
.about-bg {
    background: url("../img/about-bg.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Comment: I have one template files. page.tpl.php

Answer (score -1):

make the image php generated.
1) set header("content-type: image/jpg");
2) check from which page the request came and choose image
3) echo the binary data of your image.

Say this is in the file bg.php, you have to set background-image:url('bg.php');

Example:

```
function currentPageName() {
    return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
}
if(currentPageName() == "news.html")
    $imagedata = file_get_contents('path/to/news.jpg');
//etc

header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $imagedata;
```

Comment: i'm not completely sure of that header, could someone please comment if it's right?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this solution.  It does what you want probably, but it's overkill.  Use the CSS solutions provided by MrSlayer and tbowman.  You should use php for image generation if you have a really good use-case like compositing images or changing text in a picture.  You're not doing that in this case; you're simply using unique images that you already have.

Comment: @user1213807 here is the example!